# Gerando URL amigavel

Tags: php, url, url-amigavel

Galera, fiz uma página de cadastro de produtos, e estou querendo colocar para acessar o produto através do nome, igual ao o sistema do wordpress, porém não consegui encontrar nenhum suporte para isso.

Ao salvar o produto, gera uma URL amigavel como "www.example.com/produto/nome-do-produto" para poder acessar o mesmo sem ter que usar a ID no link.

Eu já tentei trabalhar com o `str_replace` mas gera problemas com os caracteres especiais, como espaços, aspas e outros.

Comment: Já tentou [buscar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url+amig%C3%A1vel) no site antes de perguntar? Nada sanou suas dúvidas? Então acredito que sua pergunta carece de melhorias, pois da forma que está é inviável responder qualquer coisa.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta cara.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar um arquivo .htaccess na raiz do seu site da seguinte forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?pag=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Desse jeito você vai criar um arquivo chamado index.php, que chama uma função como por exemplo a função a seguir:

```
    function getPage() {
    if (isset($_GET['pag'])) {

        $pagina = $_GET['pag'];

        $pag = explode("/", $pagina);

        $pagina = $pag[0] . '.php';

        if (file_exists($pagina)) {
            include $pagina;
        } else {
            include 'error.php';
        }
    }
}
```

Tem outras maneiras, e aqui na stackoverflow tem outros vários posts com esse assunto, da uma pesquisada ai.

Comment: Então cara, eu já uso essa parte, porém é o registro do nome como URL que é o meu problema. Um exemplo que tenho é o wordpress, que usa o nome da postagem para acessar a postagem. Vou atualizar a pergunta explicando melhor.